# How can i use a nested loops to help identify if i have 2 different matching pairs of dices

Tags: java, nested-loops

So I just had a lesson on loops and nested loops. My professor said that nested loops can help us do tasks such as knowing if we rolled 2 different matching pairs with 4 dices (4242)   I'm a bit confused on how that would work.

So I started to work it out and this is what I was able to create.

```
public boolean 4matchDice(String dice){

   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

      for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

      }
    }
```

I used boolean as the return as it will tell us whether or not we have 2 different matching pairs.

Thing is, what do I put in the the loops?  That's what's confusing me the most.

Comment: Try to change your for loop to run over the different numbers a dice might show, not the dice itself.

Comment: I don't get it can you clarify the question a bit more for better understanding.

Comment: Can you give an example of what an input would look like for parameter String dice ? Little confused as to what this method would be receiving.

Comment: @datasailor ahh so instead of 4 (which i put to indicate 4 dices) use 6 right? What would i put in the body then? I'm really new so forgive me if it frustrates you.

Comment: @JDSchenck string input for example "4224"

Comment: @learner8269 I don't know what to put in the body of the loop/nested loop. So if i input "4224" the loops should tell me (via boolean.) if it's a pair of 2 matching dices or not.

Comment: Note that `4matchDice` is not a valid method name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution I came up with, seems to be returning the correct outcome for all the test cases I ran.

```
    public static boolean matchDice(String dice) {

    char[] diceArray = dice.toCharArray();
    int pairs = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        for (int j = i + 1; j < dice.length(); j++) {


            if (diceArray[i] == diceArray[j]) {

                diceArray[i] = 'X';
                diceArray[j] = 'Y';
                pairs++;
            }

        }
    }
    return (pairs > 1);
}
```

Comment: You need to sort the input to start j from i+1 in the inner loop

Comment: Appears to be correct to me.. I have tested for the following cases:

        System.out.println(matchDice("4444")); // true
        
        System.out.println(matchDice("4114")); // true
        
        System.out.println(matchDice("4641")); // false
        
        System.out.println(matchDice("2113")); // false
        
        System.out.println(matchDice("4242")); // true

Comment: Yes, returns true.

Comment: I think we are thinking of the problem in different terms. My solution assumes that four dice are rolled together, not in sets of two. Assuming four dice are all rolled and the string parameter input simply represents the four face values of each dice in no particular order, it returns true if there are two pairs rolled, otherwise false.

Comment: ah I was reading your code as iterating 2 times in each loop instead of 4 times. It works, objection withdrawn

Comment: Lol no worries, the OP didn't really give specific enough instructions or details.. so I can see why there are so many different interpretations now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only comparing two sets with two dice each, this is enough:

```
public boolean match4Dice(int first, int second, int third, int fourth) {
    if ((first == third && second == fourth) || (first == fourth && second == third)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But if you're comparing 2 sets with any number of dice, the following algorithm would suit you better.

```
public boolean matchDice(String firstDiceSet, String secondDiceSet) {
    // validate input, string must contain numbers from 1 - 6 only. 
    // lenghts of strings firstDiceSet & secondDiceSet must be equal
    // works for any number of dice in each set.

    // The dice only match if all numbers in the firstDiceSet all present in the secondDiceSet also.
    // Let us count the matching numbers to check if this true.

    int numberOfMatches = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < firstDiceSet.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < secondDiceSet.length(); j++) {
            if (firstDiceSet[i] == secondDiceSet[j]) { // and not used
                // increment number of matches
                // mark secondDiceSet[j] as used, so that you do not count the same match twice.
                // account for cases where firstDiceSet = "33" and the secondDiceSet = "35"
            }
        }
    }

    // your dice set match if the following condition is true
    return (numberOfMatches == secondDiceSet.length());
}
```

Comment: Why use `long` ? Also `4matchDice` is not a valid method name.

Comment: `long` is not needed here, used out of habit. Edited to `int`. Had used OP's method name, removed. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just coded up a solution that will take "4242" as an input, although sindhu_sp's method is more practical i believe. I just wanted to show you another example to help your learning of java!

```
public static boolean fourMatchDice(String dice){
        int match = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dice.length(); i++){

            for (int j = i+1; j < dice.length(); j++){

                if (dice.toCharArray()[i] == dice.toCharArray()[j]){
                    System.out.println("does " + dice.toCharArray()[i] + " = " + dice.toCharArray()[j]);
                    match ++;
                }
            }
        }

        if(match == 2) *EDIT* //Change to (match >= 2) if 4 of the same pair is allowed.
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fourMatchDice("4242"));
    }
```

output:

```
does 4 = 4
does 2 = 2
true
```

Comment: For case dice "1111", this returns false. Should return true.

Comment: No it shouldnt, should it? "2 different matching pairs with 4 dices". Seems like the pairs have to be different is what I got from it. however, I'll add a comment just incase.

Comment: Hm. Interesting. The way I read it was that two different dice.. being a pair.. not two different pair values. But I see how it that could be interpreted both ways now..